How to validate PFX certificate in each of SOAP API call using Jakartha soapConnection.call() in Java
I need to validate a SOAP API call with PFX certificate using jakartha API - SOAPConnection class call()
I have tried to add the below by converting pfx fiel to jks using
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /mnt/data/NBF_2way_SSL_2021.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /mnt/data/NBF_2way_SSL_2021.jks -deststoretype JKS

Also added below lines before SOAPConnection call()
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/mnt/data/NBF_2way_SSL_2021.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "your-keystore-password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/mnt/data/NBF_2way_SSL_2021.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "your-keystore-password");

